# Running gcloud app deploy and getting PERMISSION_DENIED 'compute.regions.get', despite having Owner and Compute admin permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, permissions, app-engine-flexible

While running `gcloud app deploy app.staging.api.yaml` - i am getting `PERMISSION_DENIED`

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request to https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projects/project-id/regions/europe-central2?key failed, details: Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/project-id/regions/europe-central2'
```

sometimes its not `compute.regions.get`, but `compute.projects.get`

permissions for my `service-github@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`:
[Roles of the account service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGFbL.png)

yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

service: project-staging-api

service_account: service-github@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

A couple of days ago everything was working, but after some erroneous actions on the part of the API, all account services lost their permissions, or rather they were reset to very limited ones

After that the deployment stopped working, due to the lack of permissions, as it seemed to me... having restored the permissions on the service account that deploys App Engine, nothing has changed

I gave the `Owner` and most things related to `Compute`

So I tried to recreate the service account several times and even restored service-project-id@gcp-gae-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com App Engine Standard Environment Service Agent

but this doesn't help and permissions are still rejected for `compute.regions.get` and sometimes for `compute.projects.get`

Comment: Hi there. 
From where are you running the gcloud command? Your local? CloudShell? Somewhere else?
Have you checked that, if you are using a service account to execute the command, your account has permissions over the service account?
Cheers

Comment: @MrThompson Hi. I am running `gcloud app deploy app.staging.api.yaml` from local or from github actions, both have the same issue. Mainly i am executing from service account, but also tried with my own account

Comment: So just for testing purposes. Focus on using just your account if possible so you can narrow down other factors.
IF using your account (not the SA) on your local environment, you still get a similar error I'd suggest to
- Review your gcloud account configuration on your local environment (targeting to the proper gcp project)
- Authenticate again, using gcloud auth login and afterwards use gcloud auth application-default login
Docs here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing
Another thing, is it possible that you try to deploy to another region?